# How to remove circled cross when disabled class is enabled Bootstrap HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have something of this sort but whenever I hover by cursor above the image, I get a cross like sign please see the image

[image]

Here is the code

```
<li id="dank-li" class="btn disabled">
    <img src="img/dank-logo.png" width="30px" height="30px"></img>
    <a href="#text-carousel" data-slide-to="1">
        <h3 style="vertical-align: -5px;display: inline; margin-bottom: 15px; text-transform: none; padding-left: 5px;">Hello World</h3>
    </a>
</li>
```

Could you tell me what the issue is and how to disable via CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Set `cursor: default` on the `li` element to override bootstrap default cursor on disabled content.

Comment: a little explanation does good, helps people to understand, you may also get more votes up if you do that...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `disabled` class from your `<li>`. Bootstrap is using the `disabled` class to change the cursor.

---

I created an example to show this occurring:
http://www.bootply.com/Cv0affYw82

```
<ul>
    <li class="btn disabled">Disabled</li>
    <li class="btn">Not disabled</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ...to be more exact, "twitter bootstrap is using the `disabled` class to change the cursor", otherwise this is a correct answer.

Comment: Modified it, but I think it was basically saying the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: more or less, it was just incorrect from a programming language wording perspective... another thing I'd suggest is *not* to suggest to remove the class... the OP apparently does want it, they just want to get rid of the mouse pointer changing effect... see [unitario's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42192694/2037924)

Comment: I saw that but the only thing bootstrap does is change the opacity and the cursor. I think if someone in the future finds this question, my answer is more accurately what they want.

Comment: I like the fact that you explained the reason, but you did not give the right solution (have to change my view I said above), because you're telling the OP to remove the class, even though they want to keep it... removing it is therefore not the correct answer....

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class "disabled" from your list.